Metrics on space of positioned vectors taking length into account?
I have a space of ordered pairs of ordered pairs.  These are basically vectors with a location ((start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y)), taken from annotations of objects in images.  I can treat these as simple 4D Euclidean points and use the $\ell^p$-norm induced metrics.  However, I am curious about other possibilities for metrics on this space.  One particular feature of my use case is that short vectors tend to be objects that are far away, and thus the distance between these objects is larger than appears in the image.
Are there any true metrics on this space that take this into account?  Alternatively, can I project these points into another space so that the metric in that space emulates this property?  I could, e.g. append a fifth element to each vector that is the reciprocal of the length of the vector multiplied by a scaling factor related to the size of the image.  This seems hacky, though, and I am interested in more reasoned approaches.

Just to elaborate on my proposed solution:
For brevity,  I'll use $(w, x, y, z)$ instead of $(\text{start}_x, \text{start}_y, \text{end}_x, \text{end}_y)$.
Define $proj$ for $C > 0$:
$$proj(w, x, y, z) =  (w, x, y, z, C/||(w, x) - (y, z)||)$$
Claim: for any four points $(w_i, x_i, y_i, z_i)$, $i \in {0,1,2,3}$, if
$$||(w_0, x_0) - (y_0, z_0)|| - ||(w_1, x_1) - (y_1, z_1)|| = d$$
and
$$||(w_2, x_2) - (y_2, z_2)|| - ||(w_3, x_3) - (y_3, z_3)|| = d$$
and
$$||(w_0, x_0) - (y_0, z_0)|| > ||(w_1, x_1) - (y_1, z_1)|| > ||(w_2, x_2) - (y_2, z_2)|| > ||(w_3, x_3) - (y_3, z_3)||$$
and
$$||(w_0, x_0, y_0, z_0) - (w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1)|| = ||(w_2, x_2, y_2, z_2) - (w_3, x_3, y_3, z_3)||$$
then
$$||proj(w_0, x_0, y_0, z_0) - proj(w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1)|| < ||proj(w_2, x_2, y_2, z_2) - proj(w_3, x_3, y_3, z_3)||$$
i.e. if of our four positioned vectors, the first two are about the same length, and the last two are about the same length, the first two are longer than the last two, and the 4D distance between the first two and the 4D distance between the last two is the same, then the 5D projected distance between the first two is smaller than the 5D projected distance between the last two.
I'll neglect a proof, but the idea is that the 5th term is small for large vectors and large for small vectors, and, e.g. $(1/4 - 1/5)$ > $(1/9 - 1/8)$
This solution, however, doesn't work well if the short vectors (2 and 3) are exactly equal in length and the long vectors (0 and 1) are exactly equal in length.  Then the 5th term difference is 0 for both pairs - so this solution emphasizes the difference in length more for small vectors, but does not scale directly with the length of the vectors.

I do not intend to accept this answer, as I am interested in other solutions.  This is just here to more formally illustrate what a solution might look like.
